# Calculate age from birthday in C#

Tags: c#, datetime

For a project I'm working on, I need to calculate the age of users based on their birthday (which is a DateTime object). with a few requirements:

1. the output must be in french (the entire project is in french)
2. the output is needed to be all caps
3. the output must follow these rules:

   - if the person is a newborn (less than 1 month old) return the age in days only
   - else if the person is an young child (less than 3 years old) return the age in years and months
   - else return just the years

So I wrote this CalculateAge method

Here's the code

```csharp
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace Project.Common
{
    public static class Utility
    {
        private const float YearDays = 365.25f;
        private const float MonthDays = YearDays / 12f;
        private const float ChildThresholdDays = MonthDays * 36f;

        /*
        ... (Other non-relevant utility methods)
        */

        public static string CalculateAge(DateTime birthday, [Optional] DateTime current)
        {
            if (current == null || current == DateTime.MinValue)
            {
                current = DateTime.Now;
            }
            TimeSpan diff = current.Date.Subtract(birthday.Date);
            double days = diff.Days;

            // age less than zero is not accepted
            if (days < 0) { return "Date incorrecte"; }

            // age less than 1 month
            if (days < MonthDays) { return $"{days} JOUR{(days > 1 ? "S" : "")}"; }

            // age over 1 month but less than ChildThresholdDays
            if (days >= MonthDays && days < ChildThresholdDays)
            {
                double years = Math.Floor(days / YearDays);
                double months = Math.Floor(days % YearDays / MonthDays);

                string yearsText = $"{years} AN{(years > 1 ? "S" : "")}";
                string monthsText = $"{months} MOIS";

                return years >= 1 ? months > 0 ? $"{yearsText} {monthsText}" : yearsText : monthsText;
            }

            // age over ChildThresholdDays or unknown (just in case)
            return days >= ChildThresholdDays ? $"{Math.Round(days / YearDays)} ANS" : "Inconnue";
        }
    }
}
```

The code runs and outputs the desired values, but I want to know how can it be improved.

Comment: From what aspect do you want to improve this?

Comment: I prefer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1404/12888024) solution.

Comment: If age is not less than 1 month, why do you test if it is over 1 month? You already know that it is... same for `ChildThresholdDays`.